# Black Screen problem during boot of osgeo-live 10.5 with VirtualBox on Windows10

Tags: osgeo-live

Has anybody been able to use the osgeo-live virtual machine disk with VirtualBox?

I follow the instructions from the osgeo website but the machine will not boot.

I am stuck at the GNU GRUB selection. All boot options are a black screen with an empty cursor that does not take any input.

[image]

My default params are:

[image]

The advanced options for Ubuntu boots with the message 'Initialising Ram disk' before going dark on me while the default options starts black.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that virtualisation was disabled in the security section of my BIOS. With virtualisation disabled I was not able to run 64bit operating systems such as the osgeo-live virtual machine. Starting the virtual machine with a 32bit Ubuntu caused the black screen boot.